# Angular js support for localization

Tags: angularjs, localization

I tried to find documentation in AngularJS for supporting multiple languages with no success. Is localization supported?

Comment: Lets reopen this sucker!

Comment: As currently written, this is at its core, a yes/no question.  One of great value to programmers -- even if the answer is "no".

Comment: "attranslate" is a modern tool that solves the problem: github.com/fkirc/attranslate Although "attranslate" is intended for semi-automated translations, it can be also used just for the sake of synchronizing JSON files

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Take a look at angular-translate: https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate

for all DIY folks:

You can find localized files for angular: [here](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/i18n/)

These files will help you with the build-in angular filters: [date](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), [currency](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency) and [number](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/number). Amazing... so far.

Now you want to use your own texts, than all you need is the power of angular.js dependency injection.
Create a new file like: "myTexts_en_us.js" and use $provide.value like this:

```
$provide.value("myTexts", {firstText : "This is my localized text"});
```

For details:
http://jsfiddle.net/4tRBY/24/

For real-world-use, you should **add a filter**:
http://jsfiddle.net/4tRBY/41/

Tips:

- Make sure to insert your new localization-file into your html by hand, JS or Server. (Server is the best choice here!)
- if you include one of the [angular-local files](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.14/i18n/), you do not need to set it up in your app module. (you will have $locale automatically - see the fiddle)
- add an id key to your $provide-value - and set the value to a language code you are using in your file - this will be come in handy for testing.

Comment: Maybe I'm not thinking about this correctly, but how would you incorporate multiple languages aka more than english and something else) with the example you provided? Would you do some sort of if check for the language right before: "$provide.value("providedValue", {" ?

Comment: Quick question, what do you mean by "Server is the best choice here"? Do you mean: It's preferable to process the localization on the server side?

Answer (score 18):

What you're looking for is [$locale](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$locale).

There is actually an example about [half way down the angularjs homepage](http://angularjs.org/#create-components) as well.

A snippet from their example:

```
function BeerCounter($scope, $locale) {
  $scope.beers = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
  if ($locale.id == 'en-us') {
    $scope.beerForms = {
      0: 'no beers',
      one: '{} beer',
      other: '{} beers'
    };
  } else {
    $scope.beerForms = {
      0: 'žiadne pivo',
      one: '{} pivo',
      few: '{} pivá',
      other: '{} pív'
    };
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's a "standard" per say... but it's a start. If you had a *lot* of localization to do, I think I would just create a service to inject in my controllers... something like this psuedo-code:

```
app.service('myLocalization', ['$locale', function($locale) {
    var res = {
       'help' : { 
           'en-us': 'help',
           'es-mx': 'ayudame'
       },
       'beer' : {
            'en-us': 'beer',
            'es-mx': 'cerveza'
       }
    }

    return {
       getString: function(key) {
          return res[key][$locale.id];
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, that's what they have. Like i said, you're going to need to roll your own if you want to do it any other way. That would look sort of like that service I have above, only maybe you'd have to load some files using $http.

Comment: This could work for something real simple. If you want things like translating the placeholders inside input boxes, and changing from singular to plural as counts change, some more powerful/complex is necessary. angular-gettext and angular-translate handle these things.

Comment: @Mike_Laird - the number filter and the ngPluralize directives work fine for both of your examples. In the latter case, you'd just need to setup your own `locale` service that was a hashtable of the `when` configuration attribute for you to use globally, or you could even alter your own copies of $locale and use that.

Comment: I like your example with Slovak lang as Im from Slovakia.

Answer (score 7):

I've created a module specifically for localization purposes - https://github.com/4vanger/angular-l10n
It supports message localization, parameter substitutions, change locale on flight and provides number of handy ways to use it - filters, directives etc.

Comment: I like the look of it - I was searching for localisation for my rails/angularjs app.  Rails has good i8n, looks like l10n does the same.

Comment: This looks great..!!

Answer (score 2):

Just for completeness of information - beginning somewhere within the AngularJS 1.4 stream - there will be another i18n implementation right out of the core. Please have a look at https://github.com/angular/i18n

Answer (score 0):

you can also check this out:

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-utils/pull/173

the performance is better than any of the other i18n libraries available for angular at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for i18n support then you can refer the below project which has the full multilingual capability and also easy to implement. Take a look at github project

[angularjs-localizationservice](https://github.com/lavinjj/angularjs-localizationservice)

Comment: this module is focusing on "translation" any supporting module for number ,currency filter ?

Comment: You can use AngularJs [i18n and l10n](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n) . Very easy to Implement.