# How to use Angular translate and ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I have a list of sentences in my Json file and I want:

1. Translate them with Angular translate;
2. Use ng-repeat.

Example:

JSON:

```js
{
  "MAIN": {
    "THEMES": {
      "THEME_1": "BLABLABLA",
      "THEME_2": "BLABLABLA"
    }
  }
}
```

HTML:

```html
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="item in ???">{{ }} </li>
```

Should I do this through Controller and how?

What is the better way to do this?

Comment: user translate directive

Comment: explain the problem better, also describe the controller and the variable you are using otherwise is not clear.

Comment: My controller is empty, I use angular translate as <span> {{'MAIN.THEMES.THEME_1' | TRANSLATE}} - it works. But there are a lot of lines and I want to use ng-repeat and I don't understand how to access this JSON file. Such line as <li ng-repeat="item in MAIN.THEMES">{{item}} </li> doesn't work for me

Comment: It was mentioned in my main post, it's a JSON file located in the another directory, but everything works fine if I use just {{'MAIN.THEME.THEME_1 | translate'}}, but in ng-repeat it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

For the JSON you provided you can save it in let say `$scope.data` variable and use it like

```
<ul>
 <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data.MAIN.THEMES">{{ value | translate }} </li>
</ul>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I've tried to do this in my controller as $translate('MAIN.THEMES').then(function(response){
$scope.data = response;
}
But it doesn't work

Comment: Try adding a `console.log(response)` and paste the result here. Then I can show you the exact method

Comment: $translate('MAIN.THEME').then(function (res) {
  console.log('$scope.test ', res);  
  $scope.test = res;
 })

console.log shows nothing, seems that function doesn't work or it's not returning a promise

Comment: Ok. Where is the `MAIN.THEME` is coming from? I mean where is this json object saved?

Comment: It was mentioned in my main post, it's a JSON file located in the another directory, but everything works fine if I use just {{'MAIN.THEME.THEME_1 | translate'}}, but in ng-repeat it doesn't work

Comment: I think there is some other problem but Try this for a solution.
`<ul ng-init="data = MAIN.THEMES">
 <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in data">{{ value | translate }} </li>
</ul>`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your code as a whole, but i had a similar problem with ng-repeat, and i had a solution. Try this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in ???">{{ 'MAIN.THEMES.THEME_' + $index | translate}} </li>
```

where $index is the index of the ng-repeat.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<li ng-repeat="(key,val) in MAIN.THEMES">{{val}} </li>
```

Comment: I've tried, it doesn't work because MAIN.THEMES it's not a variable. It's an object in my JSON file

Comment: then assign that json to any variable, if you are asigning JSON  to `$scope.themeData ` then view code will be  `<ul>
<li ng-repeat="(key,val) in themeData.MAIN.THEMES">{{val}} </li>`

Answer (score 0):

You should do a [bit more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12664823/angular-js-support-for-localization) [searching](http://jsfiddle.net/4tRBY/41/).

I think what you want to do is make an http call to your json file, store it in a scope variable called MAIN.THEMES and then you can access it through an ng-repeat.

```
app.controller('main', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.json('./local.file.json').success(function(themes) {
        $scope.MAIN = {};
        $scope.MAIN.THEMES = {};
        $scope.MAIN.THEMES = themes;
    })
})
```

after this, you can then pipe the results into a filter like so..

```
<ul ng-controller="main">
    <li ng-repeat="theme in MAIN.THEMES track by $index">
        Data: {{ theme | translate }} Repeat Index: {{ $index }}
    </li>
    (or @Devidas' answer)
    <li ng-repeat="(key,val) in MAIN.THEMES">
        {{ val | write_own_translation_filter }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

**UPDATE** [Added Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Esc72qt5YsTSNodphiF?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it's not really good solution for me. I've tried to get  the data like this:
 
$translate('MAIN.THEME').then(function (res) { console.log('$scope.test ', res); $scope.test = res; }) 

But it doesn't work

Comment: please edit [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/5Esc72qt5YsTSNodphiF?p=preview) and show us what your example looks like and what is not working. The example works, but i'm not sure how you need to implement it .. by the way the $translate() function is expecting some string eg `$translate('BLABLABLA').then( / enter code / );` you need to remove quotes .. eg: `$translate(MAIN.THEME).then( /enter code / );` ..